# Send Array on multiple page Symfony 4

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

Hi i have an array on first page and I want to send it on multiple page.

```
$listIlots = $data['ilots']->getData();
return $this->redirectToRoute('multiple.interventions', ['listIlots' => $listIlots]);
```

Here $listIlots it's an array but to get this value on other page it's not working

I test 3 code

```
 public function intervention( Request $request ): Response
    {
        dump( $request->attributes->get('listIlots') );
        return $this->render('multipleIntervention/interventions.html.twig');
    }
```

```
 public function intervention( $listIlots ): Response
    {
        dump( $listIlots );
        return $this->render('multipleIntervention/interventions.html.twig');
    }
```

```
 public function intervention( Request $request ): Response
    {
        dump( $request->get('listIlots'));
        return $this->render('multipleIntervention/interventions.html.twig');
    }
```

But on all tests array don't pass to my intervention page... 
How to get my array on target page.

Thx for all help

Comment: How is `multiple.interventions` route defined?

Comment: `/**
     * @Route("multiple/interventions", name="multiple.interventions")
     * @param $listIlots
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */`

Comment: what is listIlots exactly? what does your redirect uri look like, when you call $this->redirect()? perhaps it can't be properly converted/transformed/...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this annotation ?

```
    /**
     * @Route("/interventions/{listIlots}", name="multiple.interventions")
     */
    public function intervention($listIlots)
    {
        var_dump($listIlots);
        return $this->render('multipleIntervention/interventions.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: This annotation it's for pass on get the array ? Not post